# Share content: Permission Denial when using Intent.createChooser

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am currently adapting my app to Android 11.
When I want to share a file, I get the following error message in logcat:

> Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri
> content://... from pid=20333, uid=1000 requires the provider be
> exported, or grantUriPermission()

But my app is still working and sharing works without problems.

The problem only occurs when I use:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share"));
```

It does not occur when I use:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml of course I set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` to `true`. targetSdkVersion is 29.

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY_FILE, file);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share")); // error
startActivity(intent); // no error
```

Comment: You mention Android 11. What environment(s) are you testing on? Are you getting this on older devices?

Comment: I am testing this in the emulator with Android 11

Comment: Is this problem new to Android 11? Are you seeing this behavior on older devices or emulators?

Comment: I have just tested it. It also appears on Android 10, but not on Android 9 (both emulators).

Comment: If it is only in Logcat, what do you mind? In which color are those lines?

Comment: The lines are red. See https://s12.directupload.net/images/200903/bga27dis.jpg. Addendum: On a Huawei P40 Lite (Android 10) it does not occur. Strange...

Comment: I do not know what the share sheet is doing that would cause those messages to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`. It is doing all the right things for you.
For the underlying issue, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173137936

```java
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY_FILE, file);

//TODO: Use the proper MIME type. text/plain is for sharing text via EXTRA_TEXT!
// If the file actually contains text, use the type "text/*".
new ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
        .setType("text/plain")
        .addStream(uri)
        .setSubject("subject")
        .setChooserTitle("share")
        .startChooser();
```